# When should I select openid or email as scope in msal.js executin in browser

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an entirely client side web page that makes ajax calls to Microsft ASP.NET Core client REST services. Both this UI application and the web service are registered in Azure ActiveDirectory tenants. I have successfully used another ASP.NET Core app registered in the directory to do user authentication and then request a JWT token for the web service and authenticate against that. Nowhere is the ASP.NET Core Authentication code did I have to specify scopes anywhere. If I wanted to call the graph API, I requested a token for https://graph.windows.net and used that.

Looking at [this sample](https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample), which I made work in my AD, requesting a token for 'user.read' seems to be necessary. However, other samples just use `['openid']` or `['openid', 'email']`?

I know that user.read is the AzureAd pernmission to read my entire user profile with the graph api. Does that imply whatever openid and email gives me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openid` and `email` scopes are used in Azure AD v2 applications to get access to different info. They are not needed in v1 applications.

Quoting from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#openid-connect-scopes):

> If an app performs sign-in by using OpenID Connect, it must request the openid scope. The openid scope shows on the work account consent page as the "Sign you in" permission, and on the personal Microsoft account consent page as the "View your profile and connect to apps and services using your Microsoft account" permission. **With this permission, an app can receive a unique identifier for the user in the form of the sub claim. It also gives the app access to the UserInfo endpoint.**

And about the email scope:

> The email scope can be used with the openid scope and any others. **It gives the app access to the user's primary email address in the form of the email claim.**

User.Read is a scope for the Microsoft Graph API. Actually the fully qualified form is `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`. But MS Graph API is a special case :)